Button label for less than ideal workflow
I'm working on a site where users can view product inventory (let's say they're cars for the sake of simplicity) through the company's website. The user can then click a button that opens a 3rd party scheduling app in an iframe that allows them to make an appointment to go see the car. The first step in the app is to choose the location where you want to view one or more cars - there are about 10 - 20 locations. Once a location is chosen, a list of cars available for viewing at that location is displayed at which point the user chooses the car, selects an open time slot and finalizes the appointment.
So it flows something like this:

Very flawed, I know...
In a perfect world, when the user views the car on the company's website, they would click a 'Schedule Viewing' (or similar) button that would take them to Step 3 in the 3rd party app where the location and car are already selected and all they need to do is select the time slot. Unfortunately, the 3rd party scheduling app does not support deep linking of this nature (not in my client's subscription tier anyway) and the only way the app can be launched is in Step 1: Select Location.
I'm wondering if the 'Schedule Viewing' button's label should include the location name similar to this:

The location is of course included with the other info displayed on the car listing page, but it might not be fresh in the user's head by the time they get down to the button. I'd hate for them to click the 'Schedule viewing' button, be taken to a list of 20 locations, forget where this car is located, have to go back to the car listing page, etc etc. At the same time, I find it slightly confusing to click a button that says 'Schedule viewing At Location A' and be taken to page with a list of locations that you must choose from.
Maybe it would be better to repeat the location in text just before the 'Schedule Viewing' button similar to this:

Or perhaps this workflow is so flawed that it will make little difference. Any thoughts on the matter or suggestions for improvement (knowing that the flow within the 3rd party app cannot be modified) would be greatly appreciated.
EDIT:
From @CozyBro's answer (repeated here so I can include diagrams):

Visual Cue in the iframe:
If possible, add a visual element (like a colored banner) at the top
of the iframe that reminds users of the car and location they were
viewing. This could persist throughout the scheduling process as a
reference point.

I'm leaning towards:


The issue I see with this is that from the parent website, there is no way to tell what actions the user has performed in the app. So if once in there, the user decides to switch locations or cars, the banner will be displaying inaccurate information. No idea how frequently either of those parameters are changed mid-flow, but there's potential for that to become quite problematic.
Thoughts?

One way to solve your problem is to reduce the amount of steps and how the industry solves that flaw with third party apps is to show all the options available on a list and then filter them by car. Assuming thar you're using cars one option is to show CarX card, CarY card and so on. Then in each card you can include the location where the user can go and see it. If you're interesting in CarX then you can filter just that car and see the different locations to see it. So, you can schedule an appointment to the closest place. This approach solves the flaws from the first process you described, also it gives freedom to the user to see the locations and schedule them individually without messing with the third party app.


In conclusion your dependency from the third party app will be just on the data and not totally on the process. Also, you can swap the cars by other items like books, houses and so on.
Happy designs ‍

(A) You depend on the 3rd party app too much
You asked for thoughts, so I add them here, maybe it helps, maybe not.

Are you really sure, you cannot do anything about it?
Do you know if this service provides an online API which would make things so much easier?
Can you reach out to them and ask how you could handle their site in your case?
Maybe there are ways with POST/GET to retrieve and set information.
Have you tried analyze the communication with WireShark?
If it's a pricing tier thing, maybe you are not even "allowed" to use the app inside your app?

(B) Let's make the best out of it
I think the flow from the edit with the banner is the best you can get, unless you resort to screen capture solutions or similar deep level hacks.
If the user has to pick location, car and time slot every time afresh, you need to make that clear in the banner. Maybe even state that they are now forwarded into an external app and you apologize for the inconvenience of the selection process.
I think the wording "You are scheduling a viewing for CarX at LocationB" does not imply that this is accurately is showing which appointment you did make. It helps planning. Probably the user will also not get any information if the booking was successful other than through the external app or an email notification.
So maybe you are not on the worst track. If you want to improve things, consider a wording like:
You found CarX at LocationB
Please schedule your viewing:

The first line can be shortened to "Found: Carx at LocationB" if needed. Also make the banner bigger and stand out of course.
